# How to automate browser opening and login into account

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I want to automate some tasks that i do daily, to save time and effort.

Daily, when I switch on my computer the main things I do is login to Gmail and TFS server on chrome, and on Mozilla Firefox I open an other account(client account)(as these accounts are in different proxy i have to use two different browsers)

What I want is to automate this, like when I start my computer it has to automatically open and login to the sites on both Chrome and Mozilla

I have made Chrome and Mozilla to open the sites on its startup and placed the Chrome and Mozilla on windows startup(Shell:Startup) of windows, 
By doing this each time I close and reopen chrome or Mozilla, it opens those sites again, I want those sites to open only on my system first boot up not every time I open them

Can I do this? anyyy suggestions are welcome please..!!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Batch file with code like this:

```
    start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://site1.com http://site2.com http://site3.com
```

Then set the Batch file on windows startup - u now can set the startpage of firefox to google or sth. else. The Batch file will open 3 Tabs in this case.

For the login there u can use Cookies, so you dont get signed out. Do you have disabled the history?

Otherwise u can use a programm like EventGhost to capture some tasks. The Programm will emulate keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Thanks it works and i am able to login also after making some setting changes in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a software like Easy macro recorder, or any equivalent, which records your actions and repeat them. I assume in this case that all elements will be at the same position on your screen.

If you want to automatize online tasks, you can make a php script with cUrl or use a Mozilla plugin like selenium, and simply add your browser to the start menu.

Comment: Thanks.. this was my second option for the automation. but i wanted scripts for this as in my organisation third party applications are not always encouraged.